# Литература для создания красивых интерфейсов

Tags: c#

Изучаю C#, пишу CRM под личные нужды в Forms. В принципе всё получается хорошо. Единственное, это дизайн.. Я вот не могу понять, как делаются всевозможные приятные интерфейсы с плавными перемещениями контролов и т.п. 
Имеется в виду графическая составляющая программы.. Кто-то может посоветовать какую-либо литературу и технологии?

Comment: Красивый фейс и forms практически взаимоисключающие понятия))

Comment: @Сергей спасибо, Капитан Очевидность

Comment: Можете попробовать Devexpress или Telerik для WinForms, а так WPF/UWP дает гораздо больше гибкости.

Comment: Сайт, на нем ты найдешь все ответы.
В частности по дизайну формы
https://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=Form&x=0&y=0&sbo=kw

Comment: Могу предложить книгу М.Э.Абрамяна "С# на примерах".

Comment: _Грамотные_ интерфейсы - "Психбольница в руках пациентов" - обязательна к прочтению.

Comment: Плавное перемещение - двойная буферизация (double buffered) - по умолчанию отключена во многих контролах winforms.

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/, раздел "литература по WFP"

Comment: Если у вас есть конкретные вопросы - например, как сделать плавную анимацию, без мерцания - оформите, пожалуйста, в виде отдельного поста.

Comment: [Канал на Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCigNaporFrKIPHiF1FcWfwA) с примерами реализации